Failed to start jenkins continuous integration server on centos
Jenkins.service is updated to auto start when server reboots, so after server reboot, not able to start the service, keep getting error msg.
journalctl -xe
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate jenkins[25257]: at winstone.Launcher.(Launcher.java:193)
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate jenkins[25257]: at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:496)
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate jenkins[25257]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate jenkins[25257]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate jenkins[25257]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate jenkins[25257]: at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate jenkins[25257]: at executable.Main.main(Main.java:351)
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate jenkins[25257]: Caused by: winstone.WinstoneException: Please set --httpsKeyStore
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate jenkins[25257]: at winstone.AbstractSecuredConnectorFactory.configureSsl(AbstractSecuredConnectorFactory.java:57)
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate jenkins[25257]: at winstone.HttpsConnectorFactory.start(HttpsConnectorFactory.java:55)
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate jenkins[25257]: at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:343)
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate jenkins[25257]: ... 7 more
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate jenkins[25257]: 2024-06-13 10:06:10.619+0000 [id=1]        SEVERE        winstone.Logger#logInternal: Container startup failed
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate jenkins[25257]: winstone.WinstoneException: Please set --httpsKeyStore
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate jenkins[25257]: at winstone.AbstractSecuredConnectorFactory.configureSsl(AbstractSecuredConnectorFactory.java:57)
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate jenkins[25257]: at winstone.HttpsConnectorFactory.start(HttpsConnectorFactory.java:55)
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate jenkins[25257]: at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:343)
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate jenkins[25257]: Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to start a listener: winstone.HttpsConnectorFactory
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate jenkins[25257]: at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:349)
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate jenkins[25257]: at winstone.Launcher.(Launcher.java:193)
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate jenkins[25257]: at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:496)
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate jenkins[25257]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate jenkins[25257]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate jenkins[25257]: at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate jenkins[25257]: at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate jenkins[25257]: at executable.Main.main(Main.java:351)
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate systemd[1]: jenkins.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 13 17:06:10 jenkins-test-migrate systemd[1]: Failed to start Jenkins Continuous Integration Server.
-- Subject: Unit jenkins.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- Unit jenkins.service has failed.
-- The result is failed.
Thanks and appreciate any help on this.
I have create a keystore and and try to open the port that I used.
However I have setup the permission to keystore and verifies with password which was set before during generate keystore file.
